# Using the Like Operator for any type of string

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have a list of strings in our database which is causing us problems. The strings can be in the form:

`(GS)-23 West35`

`West template 'Used for scores' in performance`

`Book binding and Josephine's freebies`

`Booking for trips`

`-WestBrokes to date`

We have been using:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strAssignment As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 AssgingmentType FROM tblMain WHERE JobDescription Like 
'*" & Me.txtJobDescription.Value & "*'")`

If IsNull(DLookup("[Category]", "tblMain", "JobDescription Like '*" & 
Me.txtJobDescription.Value & "*'")) Then
Me.txtAssignmentType.Value = ""
Me.txtAssignmentType.SetFocus
Exit Sub
Else
strAssignment = rs.Fields("AssgingmentType").Value
Me.txtAssignmentType.Value = strAssignment
End If
```

The above code works for other strings but fails for those which involve the use of apostrophe i.e `West template 'Used for scores' in performance` and
`Book binding and Josephine's freebies` Would fire error along the line `Set rs = ...`.
My question is, how do I handle the use of apostrophes in lines `Set rs = ...` and in the `DLookup` function.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Have you tried to use another library? I mean ADODB.recordset or only recordset? Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset (library Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

Comment: @R35P3K7 No and I don't know of any advantage ADODB has over DAO in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the *single quotes* with *doubled single quotes* and probably reduce to (avoiding the second lookup in the table):

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strAssignment As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 AssgingmentType, Category FROM tblMain WHERE JobDescription Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtJobDescription.Value, "'", "''") & "*'")

Me.txtAssignmentType.Value = Null

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If Not IsNull(rs!Category.Value) Then
        strAssignment = rs.Fields("AssgingmentType").Value
        Me.txtAssignmentType.Value = strAssignment
    End If
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtAssignmentType.Value) Then
    Me.txtAssignmentType.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: the replace function works on the `Select` statement. The `If` condition however fails if indeed there is no record in `rs`. The `Replace` function seems to working well on both the `Select` statement and the `DLookUp`. Do you mind editing so I can mark as complete? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. But I still think you should avoid the doubled lookup in the table. See edits, please.

Comment: this is even better. There is indeed no need for the `DLookUp` when I can use the `RecordCount` property. Thank you and stay well.